# Closed Unit ball in $\ell^2$ is not compact?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness, lp-spaces

How will we prove 
that the closed unit ball in $\ell^2$ is closed, bounded, convex but not compact

Comment: [Proving that the unit ball in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ is non-compact](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/115344)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the above, convexity is straightforward.  Pick $x,y$ in the closed unit ball and $0 < t <1$.  We need to show that $\|tx + (1-t)y\| \le 1$.  This follows from the observation:

$\|tx + (1-t)y\| \le \|tx\| + \|(1-t)y\| = t\|x\| + (1-t)\|y\| \le \max(\|x\|,\|y\|) \le 1 $

Answer (score 10):

Denote by $e_n \in \ell^2$ the sequence $(0, \ldots, 0, 1, 0, \ldots)$ with the $1$ at position $n$. Then 
$$\|e_n - e_m\|_2 = \sqrt 2, \qquad n \ne m $$
Hence $(e_n)$ cannot have any subsequence which is Cauchy. (The closed unit ball is moreover bounded by 1 and closed).

Comment: how $\sqrt 2 $  has  come ??? i think  it  should be $$\|e_n - e_m\|_2 = 1$$....@ martini  can u elaborate  more...?

Comment: $e_n - e_m$ will have one $1$, one $-1$, and all other zeros. The $\ell^2$ norm will be $\left( \sum_j^\infty x_j^2 \right)^{1/2} = (1^2 + (-1)^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 + \cdots)^{1/2} = \sqrt{2}$