# Show that closed unit ball in $ l^2 $ is not compact.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I have a prove using the defination of compact set.But I want to prove it using sequential criteria of compactness.How is it possibe?

Comment: Find a sequence which does not contain a convergent subsequence!

Comment: See [Proving that the unit ball in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ is non-compact](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115344/proving-that-the-unit-ball-in-ell2-mathbbn-is-non-compact).

Comment: @ Mariano ,I know this theorem, but I am unable to constract such a sequence.can you help me to to constract it.

Comment: Well, I wanted you to think about it. For even a longer time than you had.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: sorry, I missed your comment. The cat is out...

Comment: @Marino many many thanks.

Comment: I wish there were more internet service interruptions in the homes of math students. I am almost sure they'd learn more, better and faster!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the sequence $\{1,0,0,0,\dots\}$, $\{0,1,0,0,\dots\}$, $\{0,0,1,0,\dots\}$, $\dots$

Comment: many many thanks to you.Now I try to find out another sequence.